# Angular4: Get the selected table data from a component on print component

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass the data from table component to print component by service, but I can't access the shared data in print component as follow.

data is as below:

```
[{barCode: "31568308949"
checked: true
index: 0
itemDesc: "ASHTON-250"
permPrice: 19.99
posId: "31568308949"
profit: "4"
sellPrice: "20"
sku: "77610"
state: "HR"
store: "8501"}]
```

In service setting the subject as below.

printedData is data.

```
private testDataToPrintDoc = new Subject<any>();

getTestDataToPrint(printedData) {
this.testDataToPrintDoc.next(printedData);
}

setTestDataToPrint(): Observable<any> {
return this.testDataToPrintDoc.asObservable();
}
```

In print component subscribing the data.

```
this.loglistingService.setTestDataToPrint().subscribe(data => {
  console.log("in the print document", data);
});
```

Please advice me how to share data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed Subject to BehaviourSubject and I get the latest value upon initial subscription. The semantics for this subject is to represent a value that changes over time.

Stuff that I changed:

In the LogListingService:

```
  private testDataToPrintDoc = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

```
  setTestDataToPrint(): Observable<any> {
    return this.testDataToPrintDoc;
  }
```

Here I leave you an example of how it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahwwhp.

Hope it helps you.